# Inflate foreign Layout

Tags: android

I was just wondering if it is possible to inflate a layout that is not in my own package domain. Say, for instance, I want to use the layout of Androids contact list. Is that somehow possible?

Best regards.

Comment: try android.layout.xxx

Answer (score 0):

FOr a very small list of things in the android.R.layout space, yes.  But it doesn't include the contact list.  In fact there is no "standard" contact app in Android-  Google provides a default but a lot of OEMs override it and put in their own app, which would have their own custom layouts and would not be compatible.

What you could do is look in the AOSP and see if you can find the default Android contact app and take the layout file from there.

Comment: Checking the AOSP repo was my first clue but like you said, there is a multitude of different apps for the same purpose. What I am after is getting the layout of the one that currently set as default. I am not after the contact list in particular but rather the dialer for a calling App that accepts R-calls but gives the user the impression that he is the one making the call, when in actuality he is being called back (international call cpm saving app...)